# What is wrong with my PostgreSQL statement? This runs on MySql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

When running the following query in PostgreSQL:-

```
SELECT group_, 
       COUNT(*), 
       MIN(time) 
FROM TRIP 
WHERE time >= NOW() 
GROUP BY group_ 
ORDER BY time ASC
```

I am getting error:-

```
ERROR: column "trip.time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I don't understand. Isn't `min` an aggregate function? This query runs on MySql.

Comment: The problem is the `order by time` part. You probably meant to use `order by min(time)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time` isn't a `group by` item or an aggregate term, so you cannot use it in a query that has a `group by` clause. Presumably, you meant to order by `min(time)`, which can be stated explicitly:

```
SELECT group_, 
       COUNT(*), 
       MIN(time) 
FROM TRIP 
WHERE time >= NOW() 
GROUP BY group_ 
ORDER BY MIN(time) ASC
```

Or by a positional index:

```
SELECT group_, 
       COUNT(*), 
       MIN(time) 
FROM TRIP 
WHERE time >= NOW() 
GROUP BY group_ 
ORDER BY 3 ASC
```